# Define a function in Scala that takes an Array of a wildcard as a parameter

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, collections

I have a seemingly very simple Scala question that's driving me crazy. This:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C { def foo(a: Array[_ <: A]) { a(0) = a(1) }}
```

Doesn't compile. It says:

```
scala> class C { def foo(a: Array[_ <: A]) { a(0) = a(1) }}
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (some other)_$1(in method foo)
 required: _$1(in method foo)
       class C { def foo(a: Array[_ <: A]) { a(0) = a(1) }}
```

I think I understand; is it because there's no guarantee that all elements of "A" are the same type?  Is there anyway to make this work, or am I just doing something janky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you mean

```
class C { def foo[T <: A](a: Array[T]) { a(0) = a(1) } }
```

?

This will let foo operate on arrays of `A` or its descendants, and it will maintain the type (so if you have it typed as `B` only, it'll stay that way).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  That fixed that issue, but the problem actually runs deeper, and the problem is in a similar vein, but I'm posting a new question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723338/swapping-elements-of-two-arrays-in-scala-with-wildcard-type.  I'd really appreciate if you could help with that one too.