# Swapping elements of two Arrays in Scala with wildcard type

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, inheritance

I want to do something like the following:

```
class A[T] (_arr: Array[T]) { var arr = _arr }
class C {
  def foo[T <: A[_]](a: Array[T]){
    var ele1 = a(0)
    var ele2 = a(1)
    for(i <- 0 until ele1.arr.length) {
      val temp = ele1.arr(i)
      ele1.arr(i) = ele2.arr(i)
      ele2.arr(i) = temp
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the following compiler error:

```
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : temp.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: _$1
             ele2.arr(i) = temp
                           ^
```

I'm not sure why 
    ele1.arr(i) = ele2.arr(i)
would work and 
    ele2.arr(i) = temp 
would not.

EDIT:  According to Rex's Suggestion, I changed it to the following:

```
class A[T] (_arr: Array[T]) { var arr = _arr }
class C {
  def foo[T, B <: A[T]](b: Array[B]){
    var ele1 = b(0)
    var ele2 = b(1)
    for(i <- 0 until ele1.arr.length) {
      val temp = ele1.arr(i)
      ele1.arr(i) = ele2.arr(i)
      ele2.arr(i) = temp
    }
  }
}
```

and now that compiles fine.  But when I do a test case, as follows:

```
object Test extends App {
  var p = Array.ofDim[A[Int]](2)
  var g1 = new A[Int](Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
  var g2 = new A[Int](Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
  p(0) = g1
  p(1) = g2

  (new C).foo(p)
  p.foreach{ x => println(x.arr.deep.mkString(",")) }
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
src/Test.scala:22: error: inferred type arguments [A[Int],Nothing] do not conform to method foo's type parameter bounds [B <: A[T],T]
  (new C).foo(p)
          ^
src/Test.scala:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[A[Int]]
 required: Array[B]
  (new C).foo(p)
              ^
two errors found
```

I understand that I can do (new C).fooInt, A[Int], but I'd really like to have the compiler infer it.  Otherwise it kind of defeats the purpose of a lot of what I'm doing.

Comment: From what I can tell, the common supertype of the values of the two arrays is coming back as Any, because there is nothing indicating that the two arrays share the same type of values or values with a common ancestry. For example, if ele1.arr is an array or integers and ele2.arr is an array of 'People', how would they be able to be swapped between arrays?

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you're using wildcards here instead of parameterizing the element type.  You're blinding the compiler and making it harder for it to make sure you are doing something sensible.  In particular, it realizes that since arrays are invariantly typed, `ele1.arr(i)` and `ele2.arr(i)` are the same type and thus can be assigned.  But when you assign to `temp`, it realizes that it has no idea what that type might actually be, so it infers `Any`, and then of course that won't fit back into the array because it's not *actually* `Any`; it's just lost track of what it should be.

```
class C {
  def foo[T, B <: A[T]](b: Array[B]){
    var ele1 = b(0)
    var ele2 = b(1)
    for(i <- 0 until ele1.arr.length) {
      val temp = ele1.arr(i)
      ele1.arr(i) = ele2.arr(i)
      ele2.arr(i) = temp
    }
  }
}
```

allows the compiler to know the types all the way through, which keeps it happy, and you safer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that helped but I made an edit above to demonstrate a problem with a use case for this implementation.  Thanks a lot for all the help, and if you know of a good resource or a good search term to read about this stuff, please let me know.

Comment: @MatthewSaltz - I'm not sure how to solve that one; I'd expect the type inferencer to be able to manage, but as you can see it clearly doesn't.  If you don't need to insist on a subtype it will work, but otherwise I'm not sure how to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  It's annoying because a seemingly simple problem is becoming really complicated.  I want to create a class, which is basically a container for an array of any type.  I then want to create another class that operates on any object that extends that class.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @MatthewSaltz - I haven't ever run into this before.  If I get a chance to play around with it maybe I'll find a way to keep the compiler happy, but I don't know that I'll get a chance.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Would it break forum etiquette to create a new question that's a bit more terse?  Something along the lines of what I put in the previous comment?